# Angular 2 custom validator not calling backend

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I created custom form validator for my form but I am missing something, it wont fire the backend call at all (function gets called). Been looking into this for some time but dont see the problem.

validator:

```
private phoneNumberValidator(control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return this.myService.getPhoneNumbersCount(this.param)
        .pipe(
            map((result: number) => {
                if (result > 0) {
                    return { 'phoneNumber': true };
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }),
            catchError((err) => {
                return null;
            })
        )
}
```

And here is my service function:

```
public getPhoneNumbersCount(param: string): Observable<number> {
    let params = new HttpParams()
        .set('param', param));

    return this.httpClient.get<number>(`${this.base}/getPhoneNumbersCount`, { params: params });
}
```

and input binding:

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
        phoneNumber: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, this.phoneNumberValidator.bind(this)])
    });
```

Comment: And how is the validator wired to the form?

Comment: I editted the question with the binding

Answer (score 1):

Synchronous validators and asynchronous validators go separately, async validators are the optional third argument. Therefore, you should create the form control this way:

```
phoneNumber: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required], [this.phoneNumberValidator.bind(this)])
```

(While the `[]` are optional here, I would keep them to underscore the fact that `required` and `phoneNumberValidator` are different animals).

https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl